# Starting with / converting to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kigg

I don't know much about MVC, but I have a project where I think I could use a lot of the functionality of ASP.NET MVC based *KIGG*.  At the same time I have a HTML/jQuery based template.

**How should I approach this?**

What I am kind of hoping is that I can easily pick Views with behindlaying objects from KIGG, and then easily modify it.

**Is this a realistic approach?**

Can I really expect it to be easier than working from a conventional ASP.NET app?

Comment: If you have html templates I'dd say MVC is the easiest way to go. Webforms expects you to use it's custom controls like `DataGrid` etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are tradeoffs. One is not more or less easy to work with than the other. If you need:

- Clean URLs
- Precision control over markup
- Highly unit-testable code

MVC removes the hurdles to these. However, MVC has higher barriers to:

- Highly stateful web forms (that's why the other solution is called "WebForms")
- Actually that's pretty much it, but it's a big one.

It's up to you to pick the one that helps you achieve your goals for a specific project.